# MySQL: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'STATE' at row 1 on table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST

Tags: mysql

I have this trigger:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE original_query TEXT;
SET original_query = (SELECT info FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id = CONNECTION_ID());

INSERT INTO `update_commands`(`origin_id`, `origin_table_name`, `edited_by`, `command`) VALUES (NEW.id, 'source_draft' , NEW.last_edited_by, replace(original_query, '_draft' , ''));
update source2_draft set `name` = NEW.name where `name` = OLD.name;
END
```

Basically it has two actions:

1. Copy the update command to another table(update_commands)
2. Update another table (source2_draft)

When the trigger is executed I get this error:

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'STATE' at row 1
```

The 'STATE' column is in the information_schema.processlist

How can I fix it?

Edit: some more data:
On my localhost it works fine. (version 5.7.17)

On a staging environment with version 5.6.36 works fine.

On production with version 5.6.25-log - fails (also have replica in production)

Comment: Has to be a bug only ref I can find to it is https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41686

Comment: I saw it but it is very old and no indication of the status